# Regexp with javax @Pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regexp expression on a @Pattern constraint validator. My mission is to allow the following chars:

```
a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and !“#%&’()*+ - ./?><;
```

So far I've gotten:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

which matches all alphanumeric characters. However, I've no idea how to include the non alphanumeric characters:

```
!“#%&’()*+ - ./?><;
```

in my expression. Any help much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just list it in character set `[...]` like this:
`^[A-Za-z0-9!“#%&’()*+\-.\/?><]+$`
Details at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/10bO7E/1/